# Unexpected behavior of c_void pointer in Rust FFI to C

Tags: c, rust, ffi, void-pointers

I'm new to Rust and try to implement a foreign function interface which enables C code to interact with Rust structs. The functions save results within the structs for later use. I want to compile my Rust code into a C-dll.

As a simple example, I tried to implement

- a simple struct which holds a single float.
- a function to initialize the struct with a float and return a `*mut c_void` pointer (which carries over as a `void*` pointer to C, I assume) to the struct.
- a function which receives a `*mut c_void` pointer to my rust struct, dereferences it and returns the float of the struct.

I followed these references

[Working with c_void in an FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191249/working-with-c-void-in-an-ffi)

https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2023/01/06/rust-struct-to-c-pointer-and-back/

Here's my code so far:

```
use core::ffi::c_void;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct number_container{
    contained_number:f64,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn init_number_container(number:f64) -> *mut c_void {
    let mut num_cont:number_container = number_container {contained_number:number};
    let ptr: *mut number_container = &mut num_cont;
    let voidptr = ptr as *mut c_void;
    voidptr
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_number_from_container(num_cont: *mut c_void) -> f64{

    // UNCOMMENT THIS LINE --> num_cont2.contained_number becomes 0
    // println!("{}", format!("voidptr-adress {:p}", num_cont) );
    let num_cont2: &mut number_container = unsafe { &mut *(num_cont as *mut number_container) };

    return num_cont2.contained_number     
}


fn main() {
    println!("contained number: {}", get_number_from_container(init_number_container(12.83454)) );
}
```

When I compile and run the code I obtain the expected result:
`contained number: 12.83454`
However, if I uncomment the `println!(...)` line, which prints the memory address the c_void pointer is pointing to, I get the result:

```
contained number: 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001134413904036
```

To my surprise, printing the memory address apparently resetted the value contained in the rust struct. I guess I've made a mistake during the referencing or dereferencing process. Does anybody have an idea what's wrong here?
bonus question: How to correctly implement this in the context of a Rust FFI to C?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I think I got it done correctly now.
Here's my improved example using raw pointers and a function to free the memory:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct number_container{
    contained_number:f64,
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn init_number_container(number:f64) -> *mut number_container {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(number_container { contained_number: (number) }))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn free_number_container(num_cont:*mut number_container)
{
    unsafe
    {   
        assert!(!num_cont.is_null());
        drop(Box::from_raw(num_cont));
    }
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_number_from_container(num_cont: *mut number_container) -> f64{
    
    return unsafe { (*num_cont).contained_number }

}


fn main() {

    let num_cont: *mut number_container = init_number_container2(12.83454);
    println!("{}", format!("pointer-adress {:p}", &num_cont) );
    println!("contained number: {}", get_number_from_container(num_cont) );
    free_number_container(num_cont);

}
```

For the sake of completeness, my C-header file looks like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *init_number_container(double number);

double get_number_from_container(void *num_cont);

void free_number_container(void* num_cont);
```

If you create the header with cbindgen, it will use `number_container*` pointers instead of `void*` pointers. As @Chayim Friedman pointed out, one can safely change the type of the pointers to `void*` as Rust and C's ABI are compatible.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable, but that variable is released as soon as `init_number_container` so your pointer is invalid and attempting to access it is undefined behaviour. In the first case you're lucky and the memory hasn't been reused, so you see the expected value. In the second case the memory has been reused for something else and you see garbage.

Comment: Thank you! So I need to somehow pass ownership of num_cont in init_number_container() to the caller such that num_cont isn't dropped anymore, right? However, the C-API I try to interface with requires a *void pointer to the struct-object to be returned... any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: @user578943 allocate it on the heap? You can't (safely) pass around a pointer to a stack variable in C either....

Comment: @JaredSmith If I allocate on the heap, e.g. by using `Box`, I'd return the pointer to the Box (which is on the stack, as far as I understood) and the Boxed object would still be dropped at the end, right?

Comment: You can prevent it from being dropped e.g. with `Box::into_raw()`, but then you're responsible for freeing it yourself (with `Box::from_raw()`) or you'll have a memory leak. So you will need to have some sort of `free_thing()` function.

Comment: Have you read e.g. the [unofficial Rust FFI guide](https://michael-f-bryan.github.io/rust-ffi-guide/basic_request.html)?

Comment: @Chayim Friedman: Thanks, I'll try that! `Box::into_raw()` returns a pointer of type *mut T where T is the type of the boxed object, as far as I understood. Do I need to cast this into *mut c_void if the C-API expects a *void pointer?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, if you want the Rust API to match the C API (perhaps because you want to auto-generate the C bindings), but also no, because `*mut T` and ``*mut c_void` are ABI-compatible, so you can declare your Rust code with one and treat it in C as the other. You can even return `Box` directly!

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, for the tipp!@Chayim Friedman Thanks, the ABI-compatibility should make things much easier. I generate my bindings with [cbindgen](https://github.com/mozilla/cbindgen). After a bit of research, I guess my question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278213/how-to-lend-a-rust-object-to-c-code-for-an-arbitrary-lifetime?rq=2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196972/how-to-pass-a-reference-pointer-to-a-rust-struct-to-a-c-ffi-interface) which explains the downvote ;_; . Is the `Box::into_raw()` proper Rust or more of a hack?

Comment: Definitely proper Rust and common in both FFI and low-level primitives.